# How to redirect dynamic urls to another dynamic url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a dynamic url in Laravel like this:

```
Route::get('/{slug?}/{slug1?}/details/{country?}', 'Package@detail_pro_index');
```

and now i want to Change the url to "treatment".

```
Route::get('/{slug?}/{slug1?}/treatment/{country?}', 'Package@detail_pro_index');
```

and also want details page to be redirected to "treatment" in the URL

so, i write something like this:

> Route::redirect('/{slug?}/{slug1?}/details/{country?}',
>   '/{slug?}/{slug1?}/treatment/{country?}');

but the above isn't working, please Help!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at redirects here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects

```
Route::get('details', function(){ 
    return redirect('/treatment', 301); 
});
```

Comment: This works fine, but when i do this with dynamic like                                                  Route::get('{slug?}/{slug1?}/details/{country?}', function(){ 
    return redirect('/{slug?}/{slug1?}/treatment/{country?}', 301); 
}); It doesn't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would need to pass the redirect parameters as variables to the redirect() function:

`Route::get('{slug?}/{slug1?}/details/{country?}', function(){ return redirect($slug . ' / ' $slug1', 301); });` etc. Althought this way is kind of messy, I would pass the parameters to redirect() as an array instead: `return redirect()->action(
    'UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]
);`

Comment: How to get the 'id' in the get(); ?  if I use  ['id' => $slug]   it says undefined variable.  how to get the variable and set in array?

Comment: `Route::get('{slug?}/{slug1?}/details/{country?}', function($slug, $slug1, $country){ return redirect()->action( 'UserController@profile', ['slug' => $slug] ); 
});` This should work.

Comment: This shows a error : Action App\Http\Controllers\Package@detail_pro_index not defined.

Comment: Pheww.... i solved the above error, i was not using the folders name in namespace.... Thank you soo much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to this:

```
Route::get('/{slug?}/{slug1?}/details/{country?}', function($slug,$slug1,$country){
    return redirect(url('/'.$slug.'/'.$slug1.'/treatment/'.'$country'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Middleware Redirection
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    
    use App\Models\Redirection;
    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
    
    class CheckRedirection
    {
        public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
        {
    
            $source_url = substr($request->getRequestUri(), 1);
    
            $redirect = Redirection::where('source_url', $source_url)->first();
            if($redirect){
                return Redirect::to($redirect->destination_url, 301);
            }
    
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

also register middleware in kerner

```
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRedirection::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue for redirection 301 dynamically
solution:

1. Create new middleware
2. Regiter in App\Http\Kernel in protected middleware
   Like  \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRedirection::class,
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yos7L.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. Look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2915423) why it's not a good idea to use images or screenshots.